# JQuery SlideToggle Background Hover

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle

Alright guys I have been trying to have the background of each text box slide behind to fill the whole box with the color of #0F3 on hover. Meaning between the dividers of each but have had no luck. Can you help?

http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/hWPAV/3/

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="panel"></div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">GIFT REGISTRY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-repeat:none;
background-image:url(../../Portfolio/images/lyricblast.png);

}
a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-family:open-sans, HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold, Helvetica Neue, serif;
}
a:visited {
color:#000;
}
a:hover {
color:#FFF;
}
#navigation {
width:auto;
height:30px;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
padding-top:10px;
}
ul#nav {
display:inline;
}
li.nav {
display:inline-block;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 30px;
position:relative;
}
li~li { 
border-left: 1px solid #000000;

}
.panel {
background:#0F3;
background-size:100%;
height:40px;
display:none;

}
```

JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("li.nav").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
},
function() {
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
}
);
});

</script>
```

Comment: What is your empty div (`<div class="panel"></div>`) supposed to do? Note that `.find()` searches child elements and there are no children of your list items that have the class `.panel`.

Comment: It is supposed to be the box that slides down behind the text in color #OF3

Comment: But you set it's display property to none.

Comment: I thought that was supposed to hide it until I hover over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to rectify here:

Your JS code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.nav").hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
        },function() {
            $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here the `hover` event is binded to the element `li.nav`. `find` inside li.nav returns no element as there is no element named class `panel` inside `li.nav`. Below is the modified code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.nav").hover(function() {
            $("#navigation").find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("fast");
        }, function() {
            $("#navigation").find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also I modified the styling for `.panel` and made it absolute.

```
.panel {
    position:absolute;
    background:#0F3;
    background-size:100%;
    height:40px;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NesaG/6/)